# Cant restore stock rom in galaxy y and format failure

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-y, stock-rom

I installed Hyperion custom ROM. Before installing it I made a complete backup. Then now I thought to switch back to my original OS − but it is saying some error like format failure, cant unmount system etc.

What could be the problem here?

Device name: Galaxy Y
Recovery tool: CWM
Custom ROM used: Hyperion

```
Error Report:
Checking MD5 sum
E:format_volume failed to unmount/system
error while formatting/ system
```

Comment: We can only help you if you describe *exactly* what steps you took, and at what stage you got the error message you describe.

Comment: more clear i wiped data and cache then using CWM i went backup and restore and gave restore but i got error what i mentioned before

Answer (score -1):

You can switch to stock ROM for Galaxy Y by using the latest version of Odin and downloading the stock ROM. You can find these files in other forums.

Comment: need kies??? r zip file enough